# Find out which request was used to perform an action

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, web

How can i see what request was used to perform a specific action on a website ? 
For example adding a product to cart ? 
I know its most likely via the chrome dev console but I am not sure would appreciate a beginner friendly response :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways, easiest one could be to just look at the `network` tab in Chrome dev tools, (filter by XHR), perform an action, and just see what appears as the last item in the list.

2nd:
Open the Chrome dev tools, go to `sources` tab, then on the right side, select XHR breaking point, you can select any, or provide a specific URL.

[image]